# Issue while creating new column in pyspark

Tags: python, apache-spark-sql, pyspark

I have a python function which takes 2-input parameters and do some calculation and return some value

```
def func(column1,column2):
  if float(column1)!=1 and float(column2) !=0:
    return float(min(1,norm.cdf(norm.ppf(column1) - float(column2))/column1))
else:
   return 0
```

Now i have converted this function to Pyspark UDF using :

```
udf_func = udf(func,FloatType())
```

Now I wanted to use this function on multiple columns so i am using for loop to iterate through multiple columns

this is the Dataframe I am using:
a = [
(1, 3, 4, 6, 4),
(2, 2, 2, 4, 7),
(3, 1, 5, 2, 2),
(4, 4, 3, 6, 5),
]

b = ["column1", "column2", "column3", "column4", "column5"]

df_test = spark.createDataFrame(a, b)
df_test.show()

+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
|column1|column2|column3|column4|column5|
+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
|      1|      3|      4|      6|      4|
|      2|      2|      2|      4|      7|
|      3|      1|      5|      2|      2|
|      4|      4|      3|      6|      5|
+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+

```
for i in range(1,5):
  df = df.withColumn(f'col{i}',udf_func(f'column{i}','column5'))
```

I wanted it to work in Pyspark but I am error everytime i am executing..Please help as I am new to Pyspark

Error :
line 4, in func
TypeError: _() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

Comment: can you please provide some data to work on, dont post images. Please take a moment to read about how to post spark questions:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48427185/how-to-make-good-reproducible-apache-spark-examples

Comment: I have added the data..Please have a look..Thank you for your help!